# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?' from < iOS 14

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm currently building a Headless Shopify project with this starter: https://github.com/vercel/commerce. I was testing the demo environment of it and I noticed that they're some bugs appearing from < iOS 14.

The main error is about this line below, which appears in https://github.com/vercel/commerce/blob/main/packages/commerce/src/product/use-price.tsx
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'`

[image: Example of the error]

Does anyone know why this issue start from < iOS 14 and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Support for [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) was added in Safari 13.4.

This is available for iOS 13.1 but not 13.0.

---

You might be able to work around it by configuring Babel to transpile your code for [targets](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#targets) that include older versions of Mobile Safari.

Comment: `'next/babel', { "preset-env": { "targets": { "ios": "12" } }` Like this?